# Join JSONs in javascript

Tags: html, json, join

I have two JSON objects say J1 and J2.

Both of them has respectively Id and Call_vod fields as common. Now I need to join both of them based on it. But J1 and J2 have 1 : 4 relation i.e. for every Id value of J1 data, J2 has 4 records.

Now on J2 there is a field say Product. There can be for 4 records in J2 having Call_vod value say C1 which is Id value for one record in JSON J1.

They having Product values as suppose P1 , P2 , P2, P3.

Now I need to show J1 JSON data entirely with a field say Product having value as below in an html report.

```
"P1, P2, P3"
```

Can someone please help me how that be possible?

Comment: can u give us a concrete example of your json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Turn your JSON strings into Javascript objects using `JSON.parse`
2. Merge your Javascript objects using `Object.assign()`
3. Turn your merged javascript objects back into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify`

**Working Example:**

```js
var j1AsJSON = '{"NameJ1": "ObjectJ1", "FruitJ1": "Apple"}';
var j2AsJSON = '{"NameJ2": "ObjectJ2", "FruitJ2": "Melon"}';

var j1AsObject = JSON.parse(j1AsJSON);
var j2AsObject = JSON.parse(j2AsJSON);

var combinedJ1J2AsObject = Object.assign(j1AsObject, j2AsObject);

var combinedJ1J2AsJSON = JSON.stringify(combinedJ1J2AsObject);

console.log(combinedJ1J2AsJSON);
```